# Remove negative value from an array and arrange positive value in ascending order

Tags: javascript

Get totally lost. How to write in a correct way?

```
var i = [1, -2, 3, -4, 5, 7, -6];
for (i = 0, i < 7, i++) {
    if (i[0] >= 0 && i[0] <= i[1]) {
        continue;
    } else {
        i[0] = i[1];
        break;
    } else {
        if (i[i]) < 0) i.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

document.write("array[i]");
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the native `Array.sort()` method?

Comment: Any method to get the issue done. Stefano and others edited very good of my question but somebody deleted my thanks sentence away. I prefer to remain it for those who answered my questions!:-)

Answer (score 2):

```
i.filter( function (el) {return el >= 0;});
i.sort( function (a, b) {return a - b;});
```

Comment: I am sorry, not quite understand.

Comment: After you define your array with var i = [...] you can run those two lines of code. The first removes all negatives,  the second sorts whats left.

Answer (score 0):

If you first sort the array, all the negative items are at the beginning of the array, so you can just loop through them to find the first one to keep, and take the part of the array from that point:

```
i.sort(function(x, y) { return x - y; });
var index = 0;
while (index < i.length && i[index] < 0) index++;
i = i.slice(index);

document.write(i);
```

Comment: <script>

 var i = [1, -2, 3, -4, 5, 7, -6];

 i.sort(function(x, y) { return x - y;}); 
 var index = 0;
 while (index < i.length && i[index] < 0) 
 index++;
 i = i.slice(index);
 document.write("array[i]"); 
</script>

Comment: I got only array[i] ?

Comment: @Longway_togo: You are writing out the string `"array[i]"`. To write out the array you should not put it inside a string, not use an index, and use the name of the array instead of "array", so: `document.write(i);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [7, -2, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6];
for (i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) 
{
 if (myArray[i]<0)
  myArray.splice(i, 1);
}
myArray.sort();
```